# C++ dynamic memory allocation issue

Tags: c++, pointers, opencv, memory-management

The following code gives me seg.fault (see the comment bellow) depending how I define newImagesData. If it's array everything is OK but if defined as a pointer - fault :(

```
//Mat newImagesData[FIFO_SIZE]; // Mat is a class from opencv
Mat* newImagesData;

void func1( )
{
    ...
    newImagesData = (Mat*)malloc(FIFO_SIZE * sizeof(Mat)); //if *newImagesData
    fifoInit(&newImagesFB, newImagesData, FIFO_SIZE);
    ...
}

void fifoInit(FIFOBuffer* fifo, Mat* imageData, int size)
{
    fifo->data = imageData;
    fifo->end = 0;
}

void fifoWrite(FIFOBuffer* fifo, Mat* frame)
{
    fifo->data[fifo->end] = *frame; // seg fault with *newImagesData ; OK with newImagesData[]
    memcpy(&fifo->data[fifo->end], frame, sizeof(Mat)); // OK with *newImagesData
    ...
}
```

If I use memcpy() it works fine.
I can understand what I'm doing wrong. Any help?

Answer (score 7):

You should not dynamically allocate `cv::Mat` objects or arrays using `malloc`, since this only allocates space for the objects, but does not call their constructor (which must be called in order to instantiate a type such as `cv:Mat`). Correspondingly, `free` will not call the required destructor.

You should either use `new` (coupled with `delete`) or, preferably, use standard library structures such as [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) (or ['std::dynarray'](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/dynarray/dynarray) in C++14). For example,

```
std::vector<cv::Mat> newImagesData(FIFO_SIZE); 

std::dynarray<cv::Mat> newInagesData(FIFO_SIZE); // C++14 only
```

You can then use `newImageData` as you would use a `FIFO_SIZE`-length array of `cv::Mat` objects.

Comment: True. Using new and delete operators guarantees the constructor and destructor get called, which will not happen if you use malloc to allocate memory for a class object.

Comment: @user2443309 probably just by pure luck. It looks like *undefined behaviour*.